# Disambiguate compiled classes in Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use Spring to write a document in a MongoDB, and I am getting a `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected!`

The problem is this ambiguity comes from a compiled class which inherits from another compiled class, so I can not use @Field annotation to change the field name manually.

Is there any way to tell Spring how to resolve ambiguous field mappings without modifying the classes' code?

The class I am trying to persist looks like this:

```
data class BehaviouralEvent(
    val sources: Set<BehaviouralEvent>,
    override val activity: Activity,
    override val start: Instant = Instant.now(),
    override val end: Instant = Instant.now(),
    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle = Lifecycle.UNKNOWN
) : Event(activity, start, end, lifecycle) {

    constructor(
        sources: Set<BehaviouralEvent>,
        activityID: String,
        start: Instant = Instant.now(),
        end: Instant = Instant.now(),
        lifecycle: Lifecycle = Lifecycle.UNKNOWN
    ) : this(sources, Activity.from(activityID), start, end, lifecycle)

    constructor(
        sources: Set<BehaviouralEvent>,
        event: Event
    ) : this(sources, event.activity, event.start, event.end, event.lifecycle)
}
```

When I try to persist a document with this structure (with a `MongoRepository<BehaviouralEvent, String>`) I get an ambiguous field mapping for all the overridden attributes (activity, start, end and lifecycle).

Appreciate any ideas or workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** At the time of writing there is  no way around this issue.

The mapping layer currently has no means to tell which of the properties should be persisted if one "shadows" the other. Therefore we have this check in the entity metadata.

Now, if you tried to relax the unique field check in `BasicMongoPersistentEntity` a bit for Kotlin types by adding someting like

```java
if(isKotlinType(property.getOwner()) && !propety.hasGetter()) {
    return;
}
```

the repository will no longer complain at creation time. However, the mapping layer still needs to determine which of the presented properties to persist as depending on inspection order, they still override one another and it's likely one ends up with the wrong state persisted. Especially when overriding `val` with `var`.

I've opened [DATAMONGO-2250](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2250) to investigate further and see if there's something we can do about it.